# Regex in Groovy to accept multiple lines

Tags: regex, groovy, jira

I am trying to get my script to accept comments that are "approved" or "Approved", etc. Whenever a user approves they may have some signature in the comment which is causing the script to not run.

Here is my regex thus far:

```
 def regexStr = /^[A|a][P|p][P|p][R|r][O|o][V|v][E|e][D|d]?/
```

Anyone know what I  should add to this to have it accept new lines?

Thanks.

Comment: can you please give an example for a comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using (?s) will cause the . to include new line character
Here is an example:

```
def exp = /(?s)([A|a][P|p][P|p][R|r][O|o][V|v][E|e][D|d])(.*)/
def approve = '''approved my signature
Approved new signature
APPROVED old signature
apprOved'''
approve.find(exp)
```

EDIT:
In the solution above it would just select everything from the first find to the end. therefore, here is a better solution (using (?i) as @cfric suggested in the comments):

```
def exp = /(?mi)^approved/
def approve = '''approved my signature
Approved new signature
APPROVED old signature
apprOved'''
def m = approve =~ exp
m.eachWithIndex{ match, idx ->
    println "m[${idx}] = ${match}"
}
```

output:

```
m[0] = approved
m[1] = Approved
m[2] = APPROVED
m[3] = apprOved
```

explanation:

- (?m) - multi-line support modifier. In that case the '.' would not match new line character. so any line would be checked separatly.
- (?i) - match case insensitive
- ^ - beginning of a line

so each line that begins with "approved" in any letter case, would match that expression.
optionally, you can add .* at the end: /(?mi)^approved.*/ to match the text after. "approved". in that case the output would be:

```
m[0] = approved my signature
m[1] = Approved new signature
m[2] = APPROVED old signature
m[3] = apprOved
```

Comment: and (?i) would make it case insenstive