# Groovy println prints empty string to console instead of the proper string

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm parsing output for a test I'm running as a Gradle JavaExec task. I want to  filter the output so that only errors are shown in stdout (I'm running the task from the Windows command line).

In a `doLast{}` block, I've parsed the OutputStream to a list of strings where each entry is a line:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
String log = baos.toString()
List<String> logLines
logLines = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(log.split('\n')))
```

then iterated through the list, printing each line that starts with 'E' (for ERROR):

```
for (String entry : logLines){
     if (entry.charAt(0) == 'E'){
           println "First char == E"
           println (entry)
     }
}
println "Execution complete!"
```

My output prints the first two errors, but prints empty strings for all the rest:

```
First char == E
ERROR More info here
First char == E
ERROR More info here
First char == E

First char == E

First char == E

Execution complete!
```

Why does `println(entry)` print empty strings? Obviously `entry` is not an empty string, because it wouldn't get past the boolean condition if it's first character was empty.

Comment: Quick thought 'E' in groovy is a java.lang.String not char. If you cast the 'E' as a char does it produce the same output. I probably wrong but as written  entry.charAt (0) return a Character object who's equals method is called passing in a string 'E'.

Comment: Can you show an excerpt of the log you're trying to parse?

Comment: what about using regex? http://stackoverflow.com/a/37586619/947784

Comment: Maybe `entry` contains some weird control characters that erase the printed line. Try json-encode it: `println(groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(entry))`

Comment: @Roman that helped a lot, turns out on some lines there is a carriage return \r in addition to a new-line char \n. I'm not sure why but this happens irregularly, e.g.: one line is: "testing complete \n test passed: 24 \n test failed: 3 \r\n" so unfortunately can't just split by \r\n

Comment: You can split by any combination of `\r` and `\n`: `log.split('[\\r\\n]+')`

Comment: @Roman `log.split(/[\r\n]+/)` might be a bit easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Roman had the answer: `println(groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(entry))` revealed that carriage returns \r were being used in addition to new lines \n. Therefore the solution is to split by the regex '[\r\n]+' which will separate into an array of strings at each \n or \r\n

Comment: Does that mean the solution was replacing `logLines = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(log.split('\n')))` with `logLines = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(log.split(/[\r\n]+/)))`? 
If so, please edit your answer so it can help others in the future :)